# cordova and angular: plugins not working

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova

i'm new about Angular and Cordova. 
I'm using Cordova 6.2 and angular 1.5.6.
I can get plugins working if i create a new cordova project but i cannot in my angular app. My issue born when i had to set the StatusBarOverlaysWebView = false in IOS system and couldn't make it work (both in iphone 5s, iphone 6 and in emulator too). I tried to use other plugins but none didn't work.
I googled and found that the problem can be calling the plugin after angular is loaded and that i needed to bootstrap angular manually to get the plugins working (calling them after application/device is ready). 
I followed instructions and made a lot of trying but i cannot get this work.
I cannot even fire a console log on the device ready event copying code from the cordova device ready base example from a new cordova project.

Cannot getting even StatusBar, splashscreen working on IOS.

Maybe i'm just missing a missy thing.

Here's my code, thank you!

**myApp.js**

```
window.addEventListener('deviceready', function onDeviceReady() {
    //Never fired!!!!!!
    console.log("readydevice");
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);

}, false);

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function onDeviceReady() {
    //Fired but console returns: StatusBar is not defined 
    console.log("readyDom");
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);

}, false);



angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'mobile-angular-ui',
    'ngSanitize'
]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>My app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/general.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/custom.css"/>
    <script src="dist/js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.gestures.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/config.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-csp="">

<div class="app">
    <top-bar></top-bar>

    <div class="app-body">
        <div ng-view class="app-content scrollable-content"></div>
    </div>

    <menu-bottom></menu-bottom>

</div>

<script src="javascript/myApp.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/controllers/route.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/controllers/controller.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/directives/directive.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.com" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>
        My App
    </description>
    <author email="develop@example.com" href="http://www.example.com">
        My Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.1.1" />
    <engine name="windows" spec="~4.3.2" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="splashscreen" value="splash" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <!--<splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/images/splash.png" />-->
        <!--<splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/images/splash.png" />-->
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="true" />
        <!--<splash src="res/images/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>-->
        <!--<splash src="res/images/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>-->
    </platform>
    <icon src="res/images/icon.png" />

</widget>
```

Comment: How did you setup your project? It seems you're not including cordova something like that `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`....

Comment: I had the same doubt today. If i logged window.cordova always obtained null. I set up by cordova cli, following the guide at the official site https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/ 

I also tried to add the script under www but i got no results. If i go in the platform build apk/appx/ipa i see the cordova js. What am i doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: Hmm if I setup a new project with the cli (v 6.2.0) I can clearly see the reference to cordova.js in the index.html... Maybe retry creating your project and if that fails I would recommend updating cordova.

Comment: Damn man, i was struggling just for the cordova.js. I removed to avoid browser console error and completely forgot to add it.

Thank you!

Comment: Glad you figured it out ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to add:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

in index.html.